# Como converter uma list em string e vice versa?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, arraylist

Tenho uma list: ('47075', 'josenestle', 'i need help')
Faço str1 = str(list) e tenho em string.

No entanto se fizer list(str1) não recupero a minha list.

Não encontro solução óbvia, ajuda seria muito agradecida.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentado, a resposta apresentada não soluciona o problema apresentado. Se você possui um objeto, deseja convertê-lo para uma *string* e posteriormente convertê-lo de volta, você precisará utilizar alguma técnica de serialização. No Python, a biblioteca mais comum para isso é a [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Para serializar, *aka* converter o objeto para uma representação em *string*, utiliza-se a função `pickle.dumps()` e para converter de volta para o objeto original utiliza-se a função `pickle.loads()`, vide documentação.

Considerando que você possui o objeto:

```
obj = ('47075', 'josenestle', 'i need help')
```

Você pode serializá-lo com:

```
obj_serialized = pickle.dumps(obj)
```

Desta forma, você terá uma sequência de *bytes* que representa o seu objeto. A exemplo, o valor de `obj_serialized` será:

```
b'\x80\x03X\x05\x00\x00\x0047075q\x00X\n\x00\x00\x00josenestleq\x01X\x0b\x00\x00\x00i need helpq\x02\x87q\x03.'
```

Depois que fazer tudo que for necessário com o objeto *serializado*, você pode recuperar o objeto com:

```
obj_recuperado = pickle.loads(obj_serialized)
```

Obtendo:

```
('47075', 'josenestle', 'i need help')
```

Que representa exatamente o objeto original. Perceba que não é o mesmo objeto, mas sim um objeto com o mesmo valor. Pode comprovar isso ao verificar a relação dele com o objeto original:

```
print(obj == obj_recuperado)  # True
print(obj is obj_recuperado)  # False
```

Answer (score -1):

**Descobri a resposta!**

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = u'[ "A","B","C" , " D"]'
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(x)
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', ' D']
>>> x = [n.strip() for n in x]
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Usando "ast.literal_eval" tenho uma forma segura de avaliar strings literalmente.

Comment: Isso não tem a ver com a tua pergunta, esta solução bem podia passar sem `literal_eval`, no final das contas só estás a retirar os espaços dos elementos da lista. Ainda bem resolveste na mesma

Comment: Sim eu sei, provavelmente fui pouco explicíto mas penso que assim abrange outras hipóteses em que a string não seja tão similar à list. Obrigado pela ajuda na mesma! Será que podiamos falar por forma de mensagem privada? Precisava de ajuda com outro assunto @Miguel

Comment: visto @miguel vou mandar mail, obg